# Graceful restart to keep connections open

Tags: go, restart

I am sure I saw some open source server written in Go that was able to restart and keep connections open.

I can't find it to learn that technique.

I know apache.httpd has `apachectl graceful` that restarts and keeps connections open.

How does it done in general and in Go?

I thought it must fork and 1 exit, 2 exec(new go app) and link connections by Fd.

But in Go I can find only `ForkExec` function. I think `Fork` is required.
Also `syscall` package is not very well documented.

Comment: Don't graceful restarts simply spin up the new server to handle all new incoming connections, but keep the old server alive until it's finished servicing the existing connections? It doesn't attempt to hand existing connections to the new server mid-request.

Comment: If you execute program then new program may share open files with old one.

Comment: @LilyBallard but this need for a proxy server  or load balancer behind.

Comment: @Artem do you mean to use SO_REUSEPORT and start the new instance on the same port?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CloseOnExec may help,

[FileListener, CloseOnExec and gracefully restarting servers](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/B98plzvQQN8)

[Zero Downtime upgrades of TCP servers in Go](http://blog.nella.org/?p=879)

Comment: First. link has 404 link to github. But second link has solution for TCP listener to survive restart. I believe that similar technique could be applied for opened TCP sockets. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the repo mentioned in the first article https://github.com/pantsing/gograce/tree/master